# navigation bar in popover

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

having problem with my `navigation bar`, when I present it via popover, my nav bar was hidden,
    like this:

[image]

which should be this:

[image]

my code:

```
self.popoverController = 
[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController]; 

popoverController.delegate = self;

CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[tsuikaButton frame] 
                                   fromView:[tsuikaButton superview]];    
popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100);

[self.popoverController 
 presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect 
 inView:self.view 
 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
 animated:YES];

[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 500)];
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the imagePickerController take up the whole screen? If so, have you thought of just pushing it and not using a popover controller?

Comment: i have fixed it, though I know that uiimagepicker should be just a popover in iPad right?